# updating the file list database after installing new font

Tags: installing-fonts

I'm using the TeX Live environement on Mac.
I've installed a new font; I've exported the downloaded `ebgaramond.zip` file to the local texlive tree:

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

To use the package, I've updated successfully the file list database via the Terminal by

```
sudo /usr/local/texlive2012/bin/x86_64-darwin/texhash
```

How do I now update the map files? I tried

```
sudo -H updmap-sys --force --enable Map=ebgaramond.map
```

but there was the return: `updmap-sys` command not found

I would be very helpful if there would be a helping hand. Thx a lot
Simon

Comment: You are five years behind. Why not upgrade to MacTeX 2017?

Comment: Do you have `updmap`?  Then you could pass the `-sys` option.

Comment: In response to your question, mistakenly posted as an answer: No, what @AndrewSwann meant to say is that you run `updmap -sys …`   (note the space) instead of the non-existing `updmap-sys …`. (I don't know myself what does or does not work in TeX Live 2012.)